# INNER and OUTER JOIN on 3 tables in PIG

Tags: join, apache-pig

I am trying to convert the following join statement into PIG.

```
from EXCH e
JOIN (select a,p, count(buyer) from EXCH group by a, p) sq on e.a = sq.a and e.p = sq.p
left outer join myimplocal i on e.a = i.a and e.p = i.p and e.f = i.f and i.imp > 0 and e.iswin = 1
```

Currently, I have this:

```
EXCH2 = FOREACH EXCH GENERATE a, p, buyer; 
EXCH2_groupby = GROUP EXCH2 BY (a, p); 
EXCH_alias_sq = FOREACH EXCH2_groupby GENERATE EXCH2.a, EXCH2.p, COUNT(EXCH2.buyer);
join_EXCH_and_EXCH_alias_sq = JOIN EXCH by (a, p), EXCH_alias_sq by (a, p);
myimplocal_filterby_imp_notZero = FILTER myimplocal BY imp > 0;
```

Should I filter `e.iswin=1` before doing the left outer join? Should I apply the filter to `join_EXCH_and_EXCH_alias_sq`, then do an outer join on  `myimplocal_filterby_imp_notZero`
and my filter alias?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please make an attempt to come up with the answer and show where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In my question - as e.iswin is performed during the outerjoin on the result of the inner join tables, I had to use Union to give me the correct result. 
This is what I did:
Data Set 1:
1) inner join EXCH_and_EXCH_alias_sq
2) filter the result with e.iswin =1, 
3)left outer join the result in step 2 with myimplocal

Data set 2:
1) inner join EXCH_and_EXCH_alias_sq (same as (1)above)
2) filter the result with e.iswin =0

UNION ONSCHEMA (alias for step 3 from Data set 1) (alias for step 2 from Data set 2)

This gave me the correct result.